# variable not incrementing by one to equal the correct switch case method

Tags: java, android, imageview, switch-statement, android-imageview

I know im doing something wrong but I really cant figure out what it is, What I am trying to accomplish is have the switch statement know if One ImageView is gone then let me know one is gone.  and move to number 2 if two image views are gone then move to number three.   It works with number one but doesn't move two number two if a write this code here

**WORKING CODE**

```
         if (numOne == ImageView.GONE) {
                 Toast.makeText(.......).show()
            }
         if (numTwo == ImageView.GONE + 2) {
                  Toast.makeText(.......).show() 
             }
```

I understand that it wont flow through the if statement if the first statement is true, and that's why I need a switch statement so it goes through all of them

here is my **SWITCH STATEMENT**  ** EDITED SWITCH STATEMENT

```
  public void checkIfCorrect() {
      //checking the game to see if the numbers are correct

             int numOne   = ImageView.GONE;
         int numTwo   = ImageView.GONE + 2;
         int numThree = ImageView.GONE + 3;
         int numFour  = ImageView.GONE + 4;
         int numFive  = ImageView.GONE + 5;
         int numSix   = ImageView.GONE + 6;
         int numSeven = ImageView.GONE + 7;
         int numEight = ImageView.GONE + 8;
         int numNine  = ImageView.GONE + 9;
         int numTen   = ImageView.GONE + 10;

      switch (iGone = 0){ //tried using switch (ImageView.GONE) didn't work
        case 1:
            if (numOne == ImageView.GONE) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "One Gone Now Put two in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            };
        break;
         case 2:
             if (numTwo == ImageView.GONE + 2){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Two Gone Now Put Three in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             };
        break; 
         case 3:
             if (numThree == ImageView.GONE + 3) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Three Gone Now Put Four in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }
        break;
         case 4: 
             if (numFour == ImageView.GONE + 4){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Four Gone Now Put Five in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        break;
         case 5:
             if (numFive == ImageView.GONE + 5) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Five Gone Now Put two in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        break;

      }
```

again what I am trying to accomplish is When one ImageView is gone let me know and tell me that one is gone then move on two starting from 0 and counting up to TWO, then once you finish number two start at 0 again and count to number 3 ect......

**EDIT WHAT IM TRYING TO DO**

So what I am trying to do is count to 10. doing this by removing imageviews, When the imageview hits a certain location it will be removed, I want this code that I posted above to check how many imageViews are removed, saying that if 0 are removed im at number 1, if 1 image views are removed im at number 2 ect ect....... please let me know how to make it more clear

**answering everyones question**

For some reason its not letting me comment below everyone like I have a restriction or something so im going to explain it a little more
@Shiva, I only want it to go to case one after case one is finished maybe if I added this it will help everyone understand

**Code for one of my imageViews**

```
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int x = (int)event.getX();
                  int y = (int)event.getY();

                   switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
                         //touch down so check if finger is on ball
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                             //



                        break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                          //moves the image with the finger
                          if (mImageView16.getX() > 0 && mImageView16.getY() >0) {
                              mImageView16.setX(x + mImageView16.getX());
                              mImageView16.setY(y + mImageView16.getY());

                          }// color square 50 50
                          if (mImageView16.getX() >= 430 && mImageView16.getX()<= 470 && mImageView16.getY() >= 80  && mImageView16.getY() <= 120) { //colorsquare RGBY
                               mImageView16.setVisibility(gone);    

                             } else {

                                 }
                          break;

                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                          // touch drop will do things here after drop
                             checkIfCorrect();



                }

                    return true;
             }       

              }); // one more bracket then end of class
        } // end of class
```

Now im calling check if correct after dropping the ImageView, now when I call check if correct I want to know if the class check if correct is correct and what number they are on.  If they are on the first number 1 then count to number one.  If they are on number 2 then count to number 2 starting from 0 imageviews gone  I hope this clears things up.

@nachokk wouldn't that make iGone a Boolean therefore making it not compatible with a switch statement?  again I know this should be a comment but my comments are not working?

ok for some reason comments are not going through on IE 10

now I added this and it increments through the case statements going from 1 to 5

ok So i was able to find the resolution to the answer that I needed, I needed to loop through each case statement when completing the command and here is how it was done

**code**

```
       public void checkIfCorrect() {
      //checking the game to see if the words are correct

        //counting my numbers and image views gone
         int numOne   = ImageView.GONE;
         int numTwo   = ImageView.GONE + 2;
         int numThree = ImageView.GONE + 3;
         int numFour  = ImageView.GONE + 4;
         int numFive  = ImageView.GONE + 5;
         int numSix   = ImageView.GONE + 6;
         int numSeven = ImageView.GONE + 7;
         int numEight = ImageView.GONE + 8;
         int numNine  = ImageView.GONE + 9;
         int numTen   = ImageView.GONE + 10;

      switch (iGone++){
        case 0:

            if (numOne == ImageView.GONE) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "One Gone Now Put one more to get to 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 iGone = 1;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
             if (numTwo == ImageView.GONE + 2){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Two Gone Now Put Three in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               iGone = 2;
             }

             break;
         case 2:
             if (numThree == ImageView.GONE + 3) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Three Gone Now Put Four in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  iGone = 3;
             }
        break;
         case 3: 
             if (numFour == ImageView.GONE + 4){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Four Gone Now Put Five in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              iGone = 4;
             }
        break;
         case 4:
             if (numFive == ImageView.GONE + 5) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Five Gone Now Put two in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             iGone = 5;
             }
        break;
```

But what im trying to acomplish is not solved

To better my question I am trying to get the value of iGone to = a case in the case statement.  I would like iGone to increment by 1 every time an ImageView.getVisibility == gone;  Gone is a varible that ='s ImageView.GONE;  here is the code for instance

```
**gone code**

   gone = ImageView.GONE;
```

now to make things more clear every image is a class image5(), image6(),.... up to 16 all the classes are exactly the same besides the variables to which imageview they equal.

now if you look above youll see the touch class for image16(), (mImageView16)

how when it hits the setX and setY cordinates do I make it = iGone + 1 this is what I have tried

**tried this on every image class**

```
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getX();
           int y = (int)event.getY();

            switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
                  //touch down so check if finger is on ball
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                      //



                 break;

                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  //moves the image with the finger
                  if (mImageView5.getX() > 0 && mImageView5.getY() > 0) {
                      mImageView5.setX(x + mImageView5.getX());
                      mImageView5.setY(y + mImageView5.getY());

                  } //color square 1
                if (mImageView5.getX() >= 430 && mImageView5.getX()<= 470 && mImageView5.getY() >= 80 && mImageView5.getY() <= 120) { //colorsquare RGBY
                       mImageView5.setVisibility(gone); 

                     }
                if (mImageView5.getVisibility() == gone) { //colorsquare RGBY
                       ++iGone;  //HERE IS WHERE I TRIED IT
                //I have also tried iGone = iGone + 1; and iGone++; nothing works


                         }
                  break;

                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                  // touch drop will do things here after drop
                     checkIfCorrect();

        }

            return true;
     }       

      });
```

For some reason iGone =s  a different number everytime I know this because i called a toast statement inside the checkifcorrect class which is the class with the switch statement

**CHECK IF CORRECT CLASS**

```
        public void checkIfCorrect() {

      //checking the game to see if the words are correct

         switch (iGone){
        case 1:

                 Toast.makeText(this, "One Gone Now Put one more to get to 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
         case 2:
             Toast.makeText(this, "Two Gone Now Put Three in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             break;
         case 3:
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Three Gone Now Put Four in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
         case 4: 
             Toast.makeText(this, "Four Gone Now Put Five in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
         case 5:
             Toast.makeText(this, "Five Gone Now Put two in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

      }

         Toast.makeText(this, "The amount is" + iGone + "Yeah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
```

Im extremely confused as to why iGone keeps = a different number every time.

Ok so the main question now is.  How to get iGone to equal the amount of imageviews gone so that it can call the correct switch case statement?

Comment: Sounds like you want a recursive method.  So if your method above was called toastVisibility() after your Toast.makeText you would want to call toastVisibility() again.

Comment: im reading recursive now, but I would like the amount of ImageViews.GONE to be recorded so if one ImageView.Gone is Gone it finishes case statement one , then moves onto the second case statement without repeating the first.

So according to recursion after the first case statement I want to do  if (ImageView.GONE = 1) { return 0; and move to second case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok So i was able to find the resolution to the answer that I needed, I needed to loop through each case statement when completing the command and here is how it was done

**code**

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int x = (int)event.getX();
              int y = (int)event.getY();

               switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
                     //touch down so check if finger is on ball
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         //



                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                      //moves the image with the finger
                      if (mImageView25.getX() > 0 && mImageView25.getY() >0) {
                          mImageView25.setX(x + mImageView25.getX());
                          mImageView25.setY(y + mImageView25.getY());

                      }// color square 50 50
                      if (mImageView25.getX() >= 430 && mImageView25.getX()<= 470 && mImageView25.getY() >= 80  && mImageView25.getY() <= 120) { //colorsquare RGBY
                           mImageView25.setVisibility(gone);    

                         } else {

                             }

                      break;

                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                      // touch drop will do things here after drop

                        if (mImageView25.isShown() != true) {//here is what was changed
                              iGone++;//what was changed
                              }  
                         checkIfCorrect();//checking if correct moved after the if statement


            }

                return true;
```

**check if correct class**

```
        public void checkIfCorrect() {

      //checking the game to see if the words are correct
      iGone = iGone;

         switch (iGone){
        case 1:

                 Toast.makeText(this, "One Gone Now Put one more to get to 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 break;
         case 3:
             Toast.makeText(this, "Two Gone Now Put Three in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             break;
         case 6 :
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Three Gone Now Put Four in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
         case 10: 
             Toast.makeText(this, "Four Gone Now Put Five in the basket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
```

Some of the bottom class is not included because it does not relate

I am incrementing the case statements by the a certain number because when iGone is equal to that number I want that case statement to be called.  FOR example, iGone if going to increment by 1 when its dropped and is an imageview's visibility is NOT VISIBLE,

so when an imageview gets removed its going to increment by 1, 1, 1, so eventually iGone is going to =3 when it equals 3 it will call the third case statement, when it equals 10 it will call that specific case statement therefore simulating the effect that iGone starts at 0.

so for what I am creating a counting part I Needed the user to count to 1 then I needed them to count to 2, and 3 and so fourth.  and the way it counted is when imageviews are gone meaning that when an imageview disappears that is 1, and counting to one is complete.  Then I needed the user to count to 2 starting from 0, so when a second imageview is gone I needed the second case statement to be called.  BUT if I used case 2:
then what I was trying to accomplish would not work because the system does not know that a second we are starting from 0 (unless I told it to.) BUT if I told the system I was starting at 0 then it would just call the first case statement again because iGone would = 1.

that is not what I wanted or needed.  I needed the second case statement called so therefore I actually used my brain and said "ok, we know that one ImageView is already gone and I need the two more imageViews' gone to equal counting to 2.  (but logically we know that would be 3 because 1 imageview gone + 2 imageviews gone is going to =3 we obviously know that), how do I do this?"  "oh I know, Im going to call case 3: as my second case statement, because when we remove an imageview iGone is going to increment by 1, so if we remove 3 imageviews iGone would = 3, but the user playing the game does not know that. they think they are starting from 0 and counting to 2 because they already finished counting to 1.  and so fourth for case statement 6 and 10 and 15. I hope you see the pattern I tried to make

I hope I made myself clear for as many other people have this problem as me. if not feel free to email (P.S. my p button is kind of broken so sorry for missing any Ps' that should be there.

If you noticed the changed that I had to add into it. im hoping it will help someone else who cant get to every statement in the case statement when calling the class at different times.

Comment: Even your answer you gave yourself doesn’t give any hint about what your question was. You should assume that the readers *know* how a switch statement works.

Comment: Well yeah I am kind of assumimg that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I entirely understand your question, but it seems that your iGone variable is to pick a point to start executing code, and you want all the cases after that starting point to execute. If that is the case, you can simply remove the break statements.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `break` statement in a case, the switch statement will not fall through.

From the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

So, if you want to fall through, remove the break statements

Comment: sorry if I made myself unclear, but i do not want to fall through the break statements I want a new value for iGone everytime an imageview's visibility is gone. i added more code above that should help clear things up hope fully

Answer (score 0):

In a switch statement, we can only use numeric values, and as of Java 7 String literals, for equality checking.Take a look at the following and try it out in your code.

By using numeric values:

```
int number_to_compare = 3;

switch(number_to_compare) {
case 1:
       System.out.println("value is equal to 1");
       break;
case 2:
       System.out.println("value is equal to 2");
       break;
case 3:
       System.out.println("value is equal to 3");
       break;
}
```

By using String literals:

```
String string_to_compare = "A";

switch(string_to_compare) {
case "A":
       System.out.println("value is equal to A");
       break;
case "B":
       System.out.println("value is equal to B");
       break;
case "C":
       System.out.println("value is equal to C");
       break;
}
```

If you need other kind of checkings, you'll have to do it through *if/else* structure

Comment: So if I understand what your saying I can only compare one case statement?

Comment: In a nutshell, we can only compare literal values (numeric or Strings) with switch statements. About your last question, actually just one 'switch case' can be true at a time, as long as the value being compared be equal to one of the defined case's literals.

Comment: Well yes but I am calling it t different times but my main problem was getting the number of imagesviews gone to equal the correct case number in the case statement my code that I posted helped it and is a work around but if I try to start imageview gone at 0 after finishing the case 1 it doesnt work and I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this wrong, `switch (iGone = 0)`, you should change this with `switch (iGone)`. That will work.

`switch (iGone = 0)` will always return 1, **true**.

Comment: `switch (iGone = 0) will always return 1, true.` `isGone = 0`  is a variable assignation.

Comment: sorry comments are not working on IE 10, yeah i know IE issue lol... but anyway what i need to do is have the iGone value increment by 1 every time an ImageView's visibility is set to gone.  I added some more code above

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into ApiDemos. There is what you are searching for in ApiDemos/Views/Drag and Drop

Comment: Please explain because, when the imageview is gone the number iGone is incrementing randomly to a random number. I need it to increment by one. I can set it to drop just fine?  But for some reason iGone keeps equalling a random number

Comment: I know it’s a hard work but what about creating 10 different xmls and dynamically changing their content? Seems the only answer…
EDIT: Please add this code instead of Toast. Log.e(TAG, „num1”); what do you get in Logcat? Random values?

Comment: Ill have to check it out when I get home working now :(  but im guessing log.e (tag, iGone) right?

Comment: Yes. You also need to implement android.Util.Log and create a constant TAG

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm going to do but wouldn't it give me the same value as the toast message because when I move the image it says the value of iGone is 0 when and only when the imageview is gone it says the value of iGone is a number 1 through 15.....  When I drop another image the value increases... it does not matter which image view I use because it's a random value.

Comment: I don’t understand.. sorry.. can you explain?

Comment: Yeah basically I have the toast giving me the value of iGone.   When I move an imageview snd drop it its suppossed to give me the value of iGone.   If I move the picture and drop it it gives me a value of 0, if I move the picture and drop it in the location that makes the imageview dissappear,  then it gives me the value of iGone with a random number between 1 and 15.

Comment: If I make another imsgeview dissapear by dragging it to that location then the value of iGone goes up to 20-35 ect its different everytime

Comment: Ok, maybe i know what do you need. Please, set all (except the 1st image view) as INVISIBLE in OnCreate then check if words are correct: Correct? ImageView2.Visibility(View.VISIBLE) else //put code here
Hope this trick did what you are searching for, otherwise i don’t know how to help.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help in everything  and every part of it.  your were a good help.